# Contact form on maintenance mode page

Tags: 7, emails, maintenance-mode

I'm using Drupal 7 and I wanted users to be able to contact me via email whilst I'm still working on the website. So my plan was to use 'create a contact form', as I don't want to expose my email address.

However whenever I try to add an `input` element in the maintenance mode message it is completely ignored in the output. I think that this is because the message uses the filtered HTML file as I do have other bits of HTML the message that are rendering just fine, but I can't see any option to change which filter is used.

Is there a way to change the filter to full HTML or is there a better a option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are comfortable with Custom coding, you can try following route

On your theme template.php implement [template_preprocess_maintenace()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_maintenance_page/7), this will help you introducing new variables to maintenance page tpl file, something like below

```
function yourtheme_name_preprocess_maintenance_page(&$vars) {
  if (function_exists('_your_form_builder_funtion')) {
    $vars['your_custom_form'] = drupal_render(drupal_get_form('_your_form_builder_function'));
  }
}
```

Now copy the maintenance-page.tpl.php in your custom theme templates folder and on the template file, you can use the variable like any other being already used. So somewhere on your maintenance-page.tpl.php add following

```
  <div class="contact-form">
    <?php print $your_custom_form; ?>
  </div>
```

Comment: As side note, it should be `template_preprocess_maintenance_page()` in Drupal 7.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! This looks like a great solution and it is just what I'm looking for. However I can't seem to be able to get the hook working - when I use `themename_preprocess_maintenance_page` the variable isn't available in the template but when I type `template_proprocess_maintenance_page` (litterally - do I replace template with something) I get a blank white page?

Comment: You need to replace themename with your theme name so for ex. if its bartik then your preprocess function will look like bartik_preprocess_maintenance_page() and then clear drupal caches to allow drupal to register the new preprocess suggestion. The reason you are gettting white page is because of the name of preprocess function which is already declared in drupal core, so you must be getting function redeclared error (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_maintenance_page/7)

Comment: Perfect, thank you for that clarification - it turns out that everything was right but I was outputting the variable in the wrong place iin the maintenance page template (my fault; sorry). Works a treat now - thanks for the fast solution.